# How to loop a menu continuously until exit option is chosen, as well as repeat menu if an invalid operation is chosen

Tags: java, eclipse

sorry if the title is a tad confusing. I've been working on this all day so my brain is a bit fried. What I want to do is allow the user to continue to receive the menu options until “Exit” is chosen, but only one string is entered; as well as if an invalid menu selection is made, then the program would report such to the user and offer the menu options again. I'm just very lost on what to do and would very much appreciate any help.

```
    public class McLemorePProg5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Create scanner
        java.util.Scanner mango = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    //Print Statements

        //User is requested to enter a string
        System.out.printf("Please enter a string:\n");

        //User enters a string
                String s = mango.nextLine();

        //Operation menu is displayed       
        System.out.println("(1) Report the number of vowels in the string (a, e, i, o, u, y)");

        System.out.println("(2) Report the number of consonants in the string");

        System.out.println("(3) Report the number of lower case letters in the string");

        System.out.println("(4) Print out the characters of the strings that are in even positions in the string");

        System.out.println("(5) Exit program ");

        System.out.printf("\nPlease enter an operation number: (1), (2), (3), (4) or (5): \n");

        //User enters an operation
        int op = mango.nextInt();

                switch (op) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("The number of vowels in the string is " + countVowels(s));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The number of consonants is " + countConsonants(s));
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    System.out.println("The number of lowercase letters in the string is " + countLowercase(s));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("the characters in even positions are:"); printEvenChars(s);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Program ended"); System.exit(1);
                default:    
                    System.out.println("Invalid operation choice. Please choose again");

                }//end switch

            //Close scanner
            mango.close();  

}//end main

    //Methods

    public static int countVowels(String s) { //Calculate the number of vowels
        int vowelCount = 0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) == 'A' || s.charAt(i) == 'a' || s.charAt(i) == 'E' || s.charAt(i) == 'e' ||
                s.charAt(i) == 'I' || s.charAt(i) == 'i' || s.charAt(i) == 'O' || s.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                s.charAt(i) == 'U' || s.charAt(i) == 'u' || s.charAt(i) == 'Y' || s.charAt(i) == 'y') {
                    vowelCount++; } //end if    
          }//end for loop

        return vowelCount;

    }//end countVowels

    public static int countConsonants(String s) { //Calculate the number of consonants
        int consonantCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) == 'A' || s.charAt(i) == 'a' || s.charAt(i) == 'E' || s.charAt(i) == 'e' ||
                s.charAt(i) == 'I' || s.charAt(i) == 'i' || s.charAt(i) == 'O' || s.charAt(i) == 'o' ||
                s.charAt(i) == 'U' || s.charAt(i) == 'u' || s.charAt(i) == 'Y' || s.charAt(i) == 'y') {
                 }  //end if 

            else {
                consonantCount++;
            }//end else

         }//end for loop

        return consonantCount;

    }//end countConsonants

    public static int countLowercase(String s) { //Calculate the number of lower case letters
        int lowercaseCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) >= 'a' && s.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
                lowercaseCount++; }//end if statement

         }//end for loop

        return lowercaseCount;

    }//end countLowercase

    public static void printEvenChars(String s) { //Prints the characters in even positions in the string
        String evenChars = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if(i % 2 == 0) {
                evenChars += s.charAt(i); }//end if statement

        }//end for loop

        System.out.println(evenChars);

    }//end printEvenChars
    }//end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't resort to `System.exit()` unless absolutely must. Here's the outline of what you should do instead:

```
int op = mango.nextInt();

while (op != 5) {
  switch(op) {
    // your switch cases
    case 5:
      // just do nothing
      break;
  }

  // once you've processed that command, read in the next one.
  // If it's 5, the loop will exit
  // you may want to also print the menu here, so it appears after each command
  op = mango.nextInt();
}

mango.close();
```

Comment: I have to have an option 5 because my professor requires it. What would you suggest I do?

Comment: just do nothing for `5`. Updated the answer.

Comment: What would be the next thing to do? Sorry I am very beginner.

Comment: Merge my suggestion with your code and see if it works